# XPages : how to write Meta tag with a "Property" attribute (and not name attribute

Tags: facebook, xpages

To include facebook properly in our web application we have to include some specific metatags. Facebook metatags have to be written like this :

```
<meta property="og:{tagName}" content="{tagValue}"/>
```

How can we output this in an xpages app ?

For ex: in a theme I can output meta tag with that

```
<metaData>
<property>og:image</property>
<content>...URL to an Image</content>
</metaData>
```

but can not output a **property** attribute **instead of name** attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or like this

```
<xp:this.resources>
   <xp:headTag
    tagName="meta"
    rendered="true"
    loaded="true">
    <xp:this.attributes>
        <xp:parameter
            name="property"
            value="og:image">
        </xp:parameter>
        <xp:parameter
            name="content"
            value="url to image">
        </xp:parameter>
    </xp:this.attributes>
</xp:headTag>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the *attrs* - property:

```
<xp:metaData content="{tagValue}">
   <xp:this.attrs>
      <xp:attr
         name="property"
         value="og:{tagName}">
      </xp:attr>
   </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:metaData>
```